# Copy files from a mounted Google Drive to a local Google Colab session

Tags: python, dataset, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, drive

Because of a very large image dataset, datagen.flow_from_directory is extremely slow. Is there a way to copy the "data" folder on my Google drive to the local session in Google Colab? Kind of like uploading a file from my PC to the session, but from Drive.

Answer (score 5):

Found it. After mounting the drive, it's as simple as

```
!cp -r /content/drive/MyDrive/data /content/data
```

The first path is the "data" folder on my Google Drive, and the second one is the destination in my current runtime

Answer (score 0):

i hope that this notebook can help you. [link to notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/alx-xlx/gdrive-migration/blob/master/GoogleDrive_Migration.ipynb#scrollTo=QbW6PhaXiKSc)

- FOLDER_PATH - path of folder you want to copy
- DESTINATION_PATH - destination of the folder where you want to save the copy

`!cp -r '/gdrive/My Drive/FOLDER_PATH' '/gdrive/My Drive/DESTINATION_PATH'`